# Python: count occurrences of an element in a column of 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this data:

```
data = [["", "a", "b", "c"],
        ["a", "X", 1, "X"],
        ["b", "X", 2, "X"],
        ["c", "X", "foo", 3]]
```

I want to count how many `X`'s there are in every column (except column 0). Also row 0 can be omitted, that's why there is this line: `if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:`. I tried to do something like this:

```
def foo(data):
    new_data = data
    list1 = ["nums"]
    indexes = []

    for num1, row in enumerate(new_data):
        for num2, col in enumerate(row):
            if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
                if col == "X":
                    indexes.append(num2) #e.g: if indexes = [1, 3, 1, 3, 1]: there is 3 "X":s in column 1, and 2 "X":s in column 3
    indexes.sort()

    new_data.append(list1)
    return new_data

foo(data)
```

But I can't figure this out. The output should be like this:

```
[["", "a", "b", "c"],
["a", "X", 1, "X"],
["b", "X", 2, "X"],
["c", "X", "foo", 3]]
["nums", 3, 0, 2]]
```

In `indexes` list I have indexes of each column as many times as `X` occurs in that specific column. Maybe I could somehow count them and add that number to `list1` to the place of the specified column?

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: ***I have indexes of each column as many times as X occurs***: Initialize `list1 = ["nums", 0, 0, 0]` and instrad of `.append(...` do `list1[num2] += 1`

Comment: @Programmer: Check my answer below. I have modified your code. I guess that will solve what's missing in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
result = data + [['nums'] + [sum(1 if data[row][col] == 'X' else 0
                                 for row in range(1, len(data)))
                             for col in range(1, len(data[0]))]]
```

After this operation `result` looks like this:

```
[["", "a", "b", "c"],
 ["a", "X", 1, "X"],
 ["b", "X", 2, "X"],
 ["c", "X", "foo", 3]]
 ["nums", 3, 0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code.
So I added a dictionary to keep a count of how many times `X` is occurring in a column.

`data[1:]` --> will ignore 1st row
`row[1:]` --> will ignore 1st column values of each row.

```
def foo(data):
    new_data = data[1:]
    d = { i:0 for i in range(len(data))}
    d.update({0:"nums"})

    for row in (new_data):
        for col_num, col in enumerate(row[1:], start=1):
            if col == "X":
                d[col_num] += 1 #e.g: if indexes = [1, 3, 1, 3, 1]: there is 3 "X":s in column 1, and 2 "X":s in column 3

    data.append(list(d.values()))
    return data

foo(data)
```

---

```
[['', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['a', 'X', 1, 'X'],
 ['b', 'X', 2, 'X'],
 ['c', 'X', 'foo', 3],
 ['nums', 3, 0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy is handy

```py
res=[col.tolist().count('X') for col in numpy.transpose(data)]
res[0]='nums'
data+[res]
```

Or,

```py
res=numpy.count_nonzero(numpy.array (data)=='X',axis=0).tolist()
res[0]='nums'
data+[res]
```